# Unable to create build using Gradle

Tags: ios, gradle, xcode8, xcodebuild

MAC : 10.10.5

Java : 7

Gradle : 3.4.1

Created a build.gradle file with following contents

```
plugins {
  id "org.openbakery.xcode-plugin" version "0.14.5"
}

xcodebuild {
     target  = 'Hello-Gradle'
     scheme  = 'Debug'
}
```

In Terminal I run

```
gradle xcodebuild
```

**Error:**

A problem occurred configuring root project 'Hello-Gradle'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1)
>   Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar'. Received status code 522 from server: Origin Connection Time-out

**However if I use version 0.11.4 I get:**

**Error: Execution failed for task ':xcodebuild'.**

> No service of type StyledTextOutputFactory available in ProjectScopeServices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plugins {
  id "org.openbakery.xcode-plugin" version "0.14.5"
}

xcodebuild {
     target = 'Hello-Gradle'

/* If need to differentiate between iOS and android */
     type = 'IOS'             

/* Set ipa file name*/
     ipaFileName = ipaName 

 /* if u wish to create archive its necessary to set simulator as FALSE coz for archive we need DEVICE*/
     simulator = false        
}
```

Command to build an IPA

```
$ gradle xcodebuild -q makebuild -q archive -Pipa=Test-QA --info
```

If u want just to build against your target

```
$ gradle build
```